# Keycloak, Nestjs - ResourceGuard always results in 403 Forbidden Error?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, nestjs, keycloak, oauth2resourceserver

I have a NestJS REST API. I try to use Keycloak as Authorization Services. I want to secure the endpoints of my REST API with resources, scopes and permissions.

The problem is, I get a 403 Forbidden Resource Error on every request. I try to explain my whole configuration with a lot of images. Am I missing something or have I misunderstood something?

### Keycloak Configuration

**Configuration of the client:**
[image: config]

**My test rescource:**
[image]

**My policy:**
[image]

**My permission:**
[image]

**Evaluation**
To test my configuration I use the internal evaluation tool.
I have the user: "*testcustomer*" who is member of the group: Testproject. Therefore he should have access to the resource. The evaluation shows, it's working correctly:
[image]

### REST API:

In my NestJs REST API I'm using the [*nest-keycloak-connect*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-keycloak-connect)-package.

This is the configuration of the KeycloakModule:
[image]

**My Test-Controller**

[image]

My understanding of the package:
When a user (in this case the testcustomer) sends a request to the API to the following URI: "http://localhost:3002/api/test/test", the resource from Keycloak is associated with it. And the testcustomer is authorized to call this endpoint. Other users who are not in the Testproject group will get a 403 Forbidden response.

The problem is that I always get a 403 error no matter if my user is in the group and it doesn't even matter if the resource exists in Keycloak at all.

Note: General authentication or even authorization via roles works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to the owner of the package I got the answer:

https://github.com/ferrerojosh/nest-keycloak-connect/issues/137

His answer/ solution:

Ah I think its due to the fact your scopes have the `:` character in it.

If you think of the file in the official `keycloak-connect` library:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/f8e397cd7a1a763db5a45a07c3c3e40fec5cf8f2/middleware/enforcer.js#L18-L33

It splits off permission which is `permission:scope` by simply a split `:`.

What happened here is that the underyling `keycloak-connect` library receives a string of `File:files:read` and it gets sent to the keycloak enforcer as the resource `File` with the scope `files`.

tldr; the solution is to remove the `:` character in your scope. If it doesn't work out for you, you can submit a ticket to the `keycloak-connect` team as I do not have control over this behavior.